# YUI2: How to subscribe to YUI Panel hide event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I am using YUI Panel `http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/panel/` to design an application.

I want to execute some code at the time of `show()` and `hide()` of the panel.
I don't know what event to register and how that event can be subscribed in YUI?

Anyone please suggest me any tutorial or examples, so that I can solve above problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem stated in the post.

```
myPanel.hideMaskEvent.subscribe(function(e) {
    // the Event Code
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you actually want the "hide" event, not "hideMask".

```
myPanel.subscribe("hide", function (event) {alert('foo');});
```